# PHP Check if array index is set and not out of bound

Tags: php

I am reading from a csv file containing thousands of lines.

Now some lines are not properly formatted and hence when I try to read a particular index in a loop, I get Undefined offset errors.

I want to simply remove those lines. And for that purpose I have to identify which lines are causing problems.

Here is what is happening inside of loop:

```
$i=0;
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 2048,",");
$idx=$line_of_text[5];
$i++;
//do something else
}
```

The code works perfectly but I get 10-15 errors `Undefined offset: 5 in filepath` Now it is really difficult to determine those lines by just looking at the file. So is there a way to check if the row contains index 5 element and if not then show row number? I tried isset but it is not working.

Ahmar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"I tried isset but it is not working"
```

`isset` must work. Try this:

```
if(isset($line_of_text[5]))
{
    $idx=$line_of_text[5];
}
else
{
    print "incorrect line: $i\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
if( array_key_exists(5, $line_of_text) ) {
    $idx=$line_of_text[5];
} else {
    print "incorrect line: $i\n";
}
```

Or

```
if ( count($line_of_text) >= 6 ) {
    $idx=$line_of_text[5];
} else {
    print "incorrect line: $i\n";
}
```

But `isset($line_of_text[5]);` should also work.